# Using jsoup.connect(url).get() to follow javascript redirects?

Tags: html, redirect, jsoup

I originally had this question:

[Having trouble fetching the proper site in Java (second word for website search query gets cut off)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023292/jsoup-having-trouble-fetching-the-proper-site-in-java-second-word-for-website)

Basically, when I searched a website for an item with two words, for example "summer clothes" I would be redirected to a search with just "summer". From that answer suspect that it's because Sears uses javascript to redirect and Jsoup does not support javascript redirecting, so I was wondering if there is any way to fetch that website while still using Jsoup.

Answer (score 3):

The code below checks both for meta attribute "REFRESH" and javascript redirects... If either of them exists `RedirectedUrl` variable is set. So you know your target...

```
    String RedirectedUrl=null;
    Elements meta = page.select("html head meta");
    if (meta.attr("http-equiv").contains("REFRESH")) {
        RedirectedUrl = meta.attr("content").split("=")[1];
    } else {
        if (page.toString().contains("window.location.href")) {
            meta = page.select("script");
            for (Element script:meta) {
                String s = script.data();
                if (!s.isEmpty() && s.startsWith("window.location.href")) {
                    int start = s.indexOf("=");
                    int end = s.indexOf(";");
                    if (start>0 && end >start) {
                        s = s.substring(start+1,end);
                        s =s.replace("'", "").replace("\"", "");        
                        RedirectedUrl = s.trim();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

... now retrieve the redirected page again...
```