# Using JSoup to Access Site with SSO

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to access a website on my company intranet, and they use SSO. When I hit the site I am getting the SSO sign on page. However, if I were to hit the site via my browsers, or cURL, I am redirected to the expected page because I have already logged in. I tried doing:

`Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute();`

but was met with the same sign on page.

I have also tried using:

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(false).execute();
System.out.println(response.header("location"));
```

This didn't work either. What is the best way to handle the SSO?

Comment: Are you sure that the redirection is not being done by javascript? The `followRedirects` will work if the `meta` case

Comment: @alkis, no, I'm not sure it's not being done with `Javascript`. There is a pretty good chance it is. How would I handle this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038997/using-jsoup-connecturl-get-to-follow-javascript-redirects. Since jsoup cannot execute javasctipt, but it can parse it, you can use something like this

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing some cookies.

Fire up your favorite browser and open its developer console. Try to connect to the site and observe the headers (cookies) exchanged by your brower.

Provide the same headers you have detected.